# Setting a variable in a while loop, in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to set variables, so I can use them for evaluation in a while loop, in Bash.

```
while read l; do
  echo $l
  HASH=echo $l | awk '{print$1}'
  FILE_NAME=echo $l | awk '{print$2}'
  echo $HASH
  echo $FILE_NAME
done <$OLD_LOG_FILE
```

When I run it though, I get the following error:

```
./hash.sh: line 38: e5491a14c7374e7f2ee18e3095f8ac65: command not found
./hash.sh: line 39: e5491a14c7374e7f2ee18e3095f8ac65: command not found
```

Line 38 and 39 are lines where HASH and FILE_NAME are set.

I am using single quotes, and not do-quotes.

Should the HASH and FILE_NAME variables be set using a different method?

Comment: if you're only interested in the first and second fields, why not use your `read` command for that too and ditch `awk`? `while read -r hash file_name _; do echo "hash=$hash and file_name=$file_name"; done < "$old_log_file"`. By the way, what happens if there are spaces or funny characters in the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want command substitution:

```
HASH=$(echo $l | awk '{print$1}')
```

What you're using is a special syntax for executing programs with pre-set environment variables:

```
var1=value progname args...
```

Hence bash is complaining that the value of `$l` is not a command which could be found.